# Image Popup not execute in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, joomla3.0

I want to used on JH Image Popup.  - https://joomla-handbuch.com/en/downloads/jh-image-popup

I have check on IF conditions image popup was not loading in our Mobile Devices.

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
}else{
}
```

How to check PHP code using on Javascirpt?

```
$doc->addScript('colorbox-min.js');
$doc->addStyleSheet('colorbox.min.css');
```

And This file was not execute in mobile devices.?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if a device is touchable or not:

```
function is_touch_enabled() {
    return ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) || 
           ( navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0 ) ||
           ( navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0 );
}

if(is_touch_enabled()){
    //Your code
}else{
    //Your code
}
```